# How do I get coconuts?

Tags: happy-street

To upgrade my Bazaar I need rope, to make rope I need coconuts.  Coconuts seem to be something that would grow in game, but I've never seen a place where I could grow them.  How to get them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to buy a tree that grows coconuts. It's under the Decoration section of the shop: Coconut Palm. Buy one of these and plant it in your town.

> **Coconut Palm** - 
>   Cost: 1000 gold, 30 wood
>
> A coconut palm with some coconuts to pick.

Comment: Ahh.. I see now.  Will accept when the timer clears.  This game has so many menus....

Comment: And a different menu for each locale. One for the town, one for the forest, etc... Just take your time and scroll through the shop. There are some nice things in there.